# student information in a university with c++

Tags: c++

U want to prepare a code about working with student information in a university with these conditions and abilities (data should be saved on hard disk):

1- add new students

2- change data of each student

3- delete data of each student

4- give report (on the screen or printer, as user wishes) containing one of these forms:

```
- list of students in each branch

- list of students in each college

- list of students according to each year entrance
```

Consider Below tips in implementation:

1- introduce a class for any student

2- maximum number of students is 10000

3- the file which students data is saved on, should be designed as mixed access

4- with knowing the student number, the location of record should be accessible ( using hash function)

5- consider 2500 record as overflow region

**Can you possibly give me some hints about which classes I should use and how to start?**

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please ask a specific question. we aren't a code writing service.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you possibly give me some hints about which classes I should use and how to start?

Comment: You could search the internet and Stackoverflow for examples.  For example, use these search keywords: "c++ add new student".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following:
1) A class containing the attributes or properties of a student.
2) A {table} vector of all the students.
3) An {index} std::map of type .

The index will allow you to sort the students without changing their order in the array.

You may want to study *Relational Database Tables* and *Database index tables*.

As for how to start:
1. Code up the student class.
2. Create a text file containing a couple students.
3. Overload `operator>>` in your class, to input a student from a text file.
4. Write a *small* `main()` function that reads a student from the text file.
5. Change `main` to read multiple students into a `std::vector`.
6. Create a function that builds an index table.
7. Modify the `main` function to build an index table and print the students using the index table.

**Edit 1: "more help about table and index"**
The *table* can be as simple as:

```
std::vector<Student>;
```

Let's have the following `Student` definition:

```
class Student
{
public:
  unsigned int id;
  std::string name;
};
```

If we want an *index table*, sorted by name, we could use a `std::map`:

```
std::map<std::string /* name */, unsigned int table_index> index_by_map;
```

You could build the index with:

```
std::vector<Student> database;
const size_t database_size = database.size();
for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < database_size; ++i)
{
  index_by_map[database[i].name] = i;
}
```

If you want to find a `Student` by name:

```
const std::string student_name_to_find = "Meisam";
std::map<std::string, unsigned int>::iterator location =  
    index_by_map.find(student_name_to_find);
Student s;
if (location != index_by_map.end())
{
  unsigned int index = location->second;
  s = database[index];
}
```

Comment: can help more about table and index(2&3)

Comment: @MeisamSabzi: I added examples of table and index table.